# plotting multiple y vectors against different x vectos

Tags: python

I have several y vectors. I want to plot them on the same graphs but their x vectors do not match well. Is there a way to elegantly do this?

For example

```
x1 = [1,4,8,9,10,15,17]
x2 = [2,14]
x3 = [5,11,18,19]

plot(x1,y1)
plot(x2,y2)
plot(x3,y3)
```

The ys would equal whatever the measured value ends up being and they would be the same length as their corresponding x's. How could I make these all appear on the same line plot?

Comment: Where are the `y` vectors?

Comment: if you use matplotlib: `plt.plot(x1, y1, 'ro-', x2, y2, 'bs--', x3, y3, 'g-')`

Comment: Try showing us a complete example (including the Y values) so we can understand your problem.